# Вопрос про бд sqlite

Tags: sqlite, telegram-bot

Такая ситуация, делаю бота для Tg, что-то типо текстовой игры. Нужно пользователей, и на каком они уровне, записывать в бд. Я не знаю, сколько точно будет юзеров, и рассматриваю все варианты. В качестве СУБД выбрал sqlite. Если, допустим, будет 1000 и больше юзеров, sqlite будет нормально работать или надо думать над другим вариантом(mysql, допустим)?

Comment: 1000 пользователей Вы скорее всего сможете держать. Другой вопрос, сколько запросов в секунду будет бежать и насколько они "тяжелые"

Comment: Ну смотрите, таблица будет состоять из [id], [уровень], [количество жизней]. Я не думаю, что слишком много запросов будет....

Comment: тогда пробуйте. Если есть сомнения, пишите слой работы с базой и тогда если что, можно будет аккуратно подменить на что то более производительнее. То есть, не пишите прямо в коде sql запросы, а сделайте функции вида getLevelById, getUserData и так далее.

Comment: Хочу просто сразу быть ко всему готовым. Чтобы потом не пришлось во время работы бота все кардинально менять, останавливая его

Comment: И спасибо за совет

Comment: ко всему готовым быть сложно. Даже емакс переписывали раза 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дам ответ на примере
Я пользуюсь базой данных SQLite , в базе более 60 000 записей и на каждую таблицу минимум по 10 столбцов, без оптимизаций -  join будет работать очень долго (возможно 4 секунды если не больше)

Для того что бы помочь базе данных искать быстрее юзаются индексы , добавляются в индекс часто используемые поля в таблице, по итогу(на моём примере) 4 секунды ожидания переходят в 0.2 секунды
Но не надо всё индексировать , иначе добавление и удаление может происходить не очень быстро

Добавление поля в индекс

```
CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column1, column2, ...);
```